# Launch Application When SIM is ready in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I want to launch an application on SIM READY STATE

My Broadcast Reciever class executes `BOOT_COMPLETED`  but it fails to broadcast `SIM_STATE_CHANGED`

```
 @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {


          if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
              TelephonyManager telephoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                int simState = telephoneMgr.getSimState();

                switch (simState) {
                    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
                        Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State absent");
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
                        Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State network locked");
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
                        Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State pin required");
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
                        Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State puk required");
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
                        Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State unknown");
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
                        Log.i("SimStateListener", "Sim State ready");
                        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainClass.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(i);   

            }

but if i run it like 

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {

              if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
                            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainClass.class);
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(i);   

                }
```

It launches my application , How can I launch my application when sim state is ready ?

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest, add the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and also add this in the `<receiver>` :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED" />
</intent-filter>
```